# R: shiny: increase width of text input control created by `textInput`

Tags: r, shiny

I have almost completed a web app, which allows the user to subset the data frame underlying the web app, using the text input control created by `textInput`; see my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024404/r-evaluate-a-string) for parsing the string as an expression.

It would be more user friendly if I could increase the width of this text input control. Does anybody know how to do this?

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your `textInput` is as follows:

```
textInput(inputId="someid", label="somelable", value = 0.0)
tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "#someid {width: 150px}")),
```

you can add some css.

or

```
tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = 'stylesheet', type = 'text/css', href = 'styles.css'),
)
```

and add an appropriate entry in `styles.css`

Answer (score 0):

I created a `custom.css` file for things like this.

Put the `custom.css` file in a `www` directory in the app home directory.

Add this line to the `custom.css` file to make all of the selectize inputs fit the full width of their containers.

```
.shiny-input-container:not(.shiny-input-container-inline) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This is very useful for text inputs or dropdowns that have options with long names, or many options. It also just makes the app look more full. I put all of my filters at the top of the page and there is a lot of white space if I don't force the inputs to fill their containers.

Then you can control your input size easily in the ui.R file by setting the width of the column that contains the input container. Something like this...

```
fluidRow(
  column(4, offset = 0, align = 'center', uiOutput(ns("select_category_type"))),
  column(4, offset = 0, align = 'center', uiOutput(ns("select_category_group"))),
  column(4, offset = 0, align = 'center', uiOutput(ns("select_category")))
),
fluidRow(
  column(6, offset = 3, align = 'center', uiOutput(ns("select_year")))
)
```

```

You will also need to load you custom.css file in the ui.R file. You can do this as the first statement in the `dashboardBody` function if using shiny dashboard, or in the `fluidPage` function if using the standard ui.

```
dashboardBody(
  includeCSS("www/custom.css"),
  tabItems(...
```